# new attribute disappeared from product page

Tags: product-attribute

Description is not shown in product page, after some changes it disappeared i don't know the reason. After this i create some new attributes but they also do not appeared in product page. As default only sku, price, short description is appear. The problem is in the front end, back end don't have any problem, everything is appeared in back end.

When i try to reindex, error appear "There was a problem with reindexing process""Cannot initialize the indexer process."
Please give me advice, thank you! magento 1.9

[image: all new attribute (color, manufacturer, discription2 do not apear, also default description is not shown]

[image: in back end everything appeared normally][image]

Answer (score 0):

How attributes appear on your page depends on your template. In the default Magento template, the main product description, and any other attributes, are displayed in tabs below the product image. It looks like you have a custom theme installed, if you revert it to the default theme, you may be able to see the description and other attributes there and edit your template accordingly.

To make sure that an attribute is available to display in your theme, make sure that *Visible on Product View Page on Front-end* is set to **Yes** on the Edit Product Attribute screen in the admin.

As for the problem with the index.php, this answer may help: [Re-index error: Cannot initialize the indexer process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53838/re-index-error-cannot-initialize-the-indexer-process)